# Stack Overflow Jobs should include required spoken languages

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm looking for a job in an English-speaking company in mainland Europe (there are many), but there is no way that I can see to filter out companies that require fluency in other languages.

In addition, I get emails recommending jobs where the postings are entirely in German or French - which isn't particularly useful to me.

Comment: Do you think this should be on the Job end, or something in developers user profiles? Maybe users could select what languages they're fluent in, then the system could filter out postings that aren't written in those languages? This would give the control to you.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - I think it would make sense from the job end to list required languages so that it would be able to be filtered during search. As far as secondary languages which are extra, that would probably best fit in the section for extra qualifications in the job description area.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - For example, one issue with using the post's language which would be problematic would be bilingual situations where the post was written in English but also required German. Short of reading the entire description to parse out that German was a requirement (probably in the same area as experience/education/technology/etc.), it would not be possible to discern that from the user's end.

Comment: There are more levels to this. I'd be happy to work for a company that requires fluent Swedish/German/French/…, but not at a company where docs or code are written in Swedish/German/French/…. US English is the language I work in, and that's barely negotiable, even though I speak a few others.